# Camera Rendering Buffers and Stutters When Large Video Files Being Processd with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, operating-system, video-streaming, gstreamer, video-processing

When rendering a real-time camera, I use ffmpeg to process a large video file(like 4G or even larger) at the same time. I noticed that the video frames are buffering and stuttering.

Pipeline:

`DISPLAY=:0 gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/home/user/jellyfish-120-mbps-4k-uhd-hevc-10bit.mkv ! matroskademux name=demux demux.video_0 ! queue ! h265parse ! nvv4l2decoder ! nvvidconv ! xvimagesink`

FFmpeg command:

`ffmpeg -i ${file_name} -c copy -f segment -segment_time 600 -segment_format_options movflags=+faststart -reset_timestamps 1 ./${file_name}_%02d.mp4 -y`

And there are some warning indicated that “a lot of buffers are being dropped” duration stuttering.
[pipeline warning picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yE6Ih.png)

The requirement can be summarized as “real-time video rendering has higher priority, and the low rate of large file processing is accepted”, are there any possible solutions of this issue from your perspective? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Camera Rendering Buffers and Stutters When Processing Large Video Files with FFmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76060884/camera-rendering-buffers-and-stutters-when-processing-large-video-files-with-ffm)

Comment: @Anonymous Coward The link you mentioned is just asked by me lol. This one is more specific, I want to explore the answers from both theoretical and practical perspectives.

Comment: As explained by the ffmpeg tag: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for notifying me of this explanation, never noticed it before.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

its a hunch but not at the same time.
probably your processor/ram is getting overloaded which in turn reduces your gstreamer pipeline's priority which reduces the resources invested in it which slows down your pipeline resulting in bad output timestamps (according to the error message).
there are two easy ways to fix it:

1. reduce the resolution that is being output of either process to SD or HD as 4K resolution is very resource heavy
2. in your ffmpeg cmd add the -re flag before -i flag which will force ffmpeg to  read the file at its actual framerate and encode accordingly but the drawback to this is if your file is 1 hr long then it will take about 1 hour to encode but it will drastically reduce the processor/gpu usage in turn letting your gst pipeline use as many resources as possible

p.s also try increasing process priority of your gst pipeline first either in system monitor/taskmanager or using nice (linux only) but again it may slow down your ffmpeg proc.

hope i could help

Comment: Ah actually the pipeline and ffmpeg cmd I mentioned above is just to reproduce this problem, the real ones are too complicate to explain. So the parameters of them can not be modifed. I would try to use nice or ionice to lower the priority of ffmpeg. Thanks for the help!! @CodeCalf

Comment: i would also tell you to try and reduce the buffers if your process starts using swap memory as it would reduce your ram usage or you could just increase the ram of your system. swap is too slow for real time encoding/decoding. also if i may ask why arent you using ffmpeg for both the processes or gst for both of them is there a particular reason for you to use both gst and ffmpeg?

Comment: yes I noticed there is a process named `kswapd0`,  which means at that time os needed to swap in and out pages between ram and disk, right? And recently I get confused about the deep reason why camera frames lag when large file is processed by ffmpeg, does it caused by "lack of available free memory" or "all buffers(in user space or kernel) 
 at that moment are occupied by ffmpeg"?

Comment: Essentialy when your ram is full then the swap is your ram so the problem for the cpu to read from the swap is slow as hell even if you have a nvme drive...it's always lack of free memory never had buffer issues never had to even increase os defaults except maybe UDP buffers when i had like 200ch live transcoding simultaneously...    But you are also decoding in 4k that could lead to a buffer issue but not with only 2 or 3 streams you will atleast have to touch 8 streams before that happens i guess

Comment: thanks, it's really inspiring!  The pages generated by ffmpeg are marked as dirty pages in memory and then written back to the hard disk. Thus, if ffmpeg's dirty pages fill up all available memory at that moment, other processes may be unable to obtain free memory, which could cause them to become stuck. So I deeply suspect that the reason for the camera rendering lag is due to a lack of available memory to store the video data provided by the underlying camera driver. Is that correct @CodeCalf?

Comment: Pretty much any video transcoding/decoding is heavily dependent on ram as it needs high enough bandwidth to encode/decode and send the frame forward simultaneously it does this at least 25 times a second if not more depending on the fps of the video so you can imagine the need of low latency and high bandwidth memory especially if you use hw acceleration as the cpu needs to copy data from the ram to the gpu vram to offload the work to the gpu so it also uses quite a bit of ram depending on the buffer sizes you set

Comment: Also this is after considering that you have enough processing headroom as if your cpu is utilised more than 85% then it will create similar issues like introducing stutter and general choppiness